Use of comments
I am referring to Qual è una buona traduzione per Buzzword? to ask about a very general issue: the fact that here in ISE (but not only) comments are used to give answers. 
Users who are new and don't have enough reputation to comment on questions asked by other users tys to reply with an answer. And the same users who hide behind the comments punish the answers with a down-vote. I don't understand this practice, but it seems to move away new people (or at least myself) from an active participation. In the specific I ask the person who down-voted my answer, why, and what was his contribution to the topic.

Welcome to Italian.SE, @ealy! I'm really upset that you had such a bad experience! In my opinion, your answer shouldn't have been downvoted. I'll try to expand my point of view later, but I hope to keep you as an active user of the site.

Related question: https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1266/707.

@Charo, thanks a lot for understanding my point of view

I am not sure what you mean by the “persons who hide behind the comments”. Anyway, it's me who both downvoted the answer and explained in the comment why I think it was not a relevant answer, and possibly not an answer at all, but more of a remark about the excessive use of English terms in Italian. Indeed this is not what the question about a translation for “buzzword” is about: a “buzzword” might well not be an Anglicism, and many Anglicisms used in Italian are not buzzwords. I apologise for not having made clear why I downvoted the answer.

Ok, I get your point, but you seem to take only the first part of my answer. I didn't say only anglicism. I said instead tecno-anglicismi, which I agree can be related only to buzzwords about technical subjects. You have all the rights to downvote, but in my opinion your reaction is excessively severe. As for the people who hide, it's a general behaviour here, to use comments for not being exposed. I am new but curious to see what of the comments transferred to answers would be gently appreciated

I don't if anyone “use[s] comments for not being exposed”. I for one, if ever I did so, it was because in my opinion what I had to say did not amount to an answer, but just to a personal opinion or some partial material to be used by someone else and so on. This might be confirmed, I believe, by the fact that I also give many regular answers. But if you have in mind some specific case, mine or somebody else's, please point it out.

I don't have much time for that since I removed my account here. But I stayed long enough to see that the abuse of comments is tolerated by administrators so a lot of questions are left without answers because people are too engaged in commenting

@ealy Could you give some examples? I am often guilty of "answering" in comments, mainly because I don't consider what I write really "answers" (I am trying to control this tendency), but in my impression questions here are answered fairly quickly, and the problem is more often the lack of questions rather than of answers. It is true that there are some questions that are without answers, but this happens because the questions are really hard (this particular one is an example in my opinion), not because people "answer in the comments".Oh I forgot, I am sorry too your experience here was bad.

As I've already explained in my previous comment,  I'm really upset that you had such a bad experience and I would like to keep you as an active user of this site. In my opinion, your answer gives a positive contribution to the discussion so I wouldn't have downvoted it. Maybe it's not the best or the most general translation, but I feel that the expression you proposed could be effectively used in the example proposed by the OP. This is the reason why I think that it shouldn't have been downvoted. But let me insist that this is my personal opinion. 
On the other hand, I believe that nothing was done incorrectly because the user who downvoted your answer gave the reason in a comment. I don't think that people in this site try to hide behide comments. If you read the answers and comments to this other question, you can see the reasons why users do that. In short, people try to obtain high quality answers in this site. It's true that new users often don't have enough reputation to write comments. Nevertheless, if some of these users write as an answer something that he or she feels should be a comment, it's always possible to mention it in the post and then a moderator can convert it in a comment.
